# Custom Media type token for specific field

Tags: media, 9, tokens

I have a custom Media type - `gallery_image` and it has a couple of extra fields, including `field_caption`. (Drupal 9)

Do replacement tokens for custom Media type fields get generated automatically, or do I have to create one?

I want to pass the token to a colorbox overlay as the preferred caption field.

Comment: Are they not in the token browser?

Comment: I havent been able to find them no.